# How to set a click listener in a footer layout included in many layouts?

Tags: android, include, onclicklistener, footer

Good evening.

The problem I'm facing can be described the following way:

- I have many views that implements the same footer (main, list_items,
  book_item...)
- The footer, for example, has some buttons (Book Item, List Items).
- I need to define the click listener on the footer buttons in a way
  that I can reuse it in every layout that include this footer.

So far, I can only make the footer buttons work if I set the click listener in every activity related to the layouts that include the footer.

How do you suggest solving this problem?
Your help and details are much appreciated because I'm novice in android development.

My code resembles the following:

**Layout1.xml**

```
<content>...</content>
<include layout="@layout/footer_layout"></include>
```

**Layout2.xml**

```
<content>...</content>
<include layout="@layout/footer_layout"></include>
```

**footer.xml**

```
<Button>List Items</Button>
<Button>Book Item</Button>
```

Comment: do you want to share a common listener for all of your footer layouts?

Comment: Yes.
But I want to clarify that I'm using only 1 footer for all my views, and I want that footer to be able to handle the click buttons without setting the click listener in every view that includes the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a fragment for your footer_layout then add it and reuse it in each activity.

The use of a fragment will allow you to fully modularize your activities, you can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI like on tablet, and you can reuse a single fragment in multiple activities which is what you're looking to do.

Check out the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

1- Create a FooterFragment:

```
public class FooterFragment extends Fragment {

  //Mandatory constructor for instantiating the fragment
  public FooterFragment() {
  }
  /**
     * Inflates the fragment layout file footer_layout
     */
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, container, false);

        // write your buttons and the OnClickListener logic
        ...

        // Return the rootView
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

2- Create your fragment_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footer_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.android.FooterFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

3- Now you can include the fragment_layout in all the desired activities xml layout files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but although the description of fragments use seems to be what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure if answers the problem at hand.
Basically, I would need a footer that is included in many views to handle its buttons click events in every view that includes it. (switch between multiple activities)
When I read about fragments, what I understand is that they are a way of fragmenting the UI so we don't need to switch between activities.

Please correct me because I know I probably still get this wrong.

Comment: Hello! If the click listener will be doing the same thing in all activities you want to include it to, i think a fragment will work great by reusing it in other activities.
I will edit my previous answer with an example on how to do it.

Comment: Hi Tarik.
I was able to solve the problem using fragments.
What was not obvious to me is that I have to use both Fragment FragmentActivity classes to achieve the final result.

Comment: That's great! :)